# How to return line breaks in MVC JsonResult

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

I want to display a javascript alert using the message being passed back from a controller action that returns Json result. I want this message to have line breaks in it.

Here is my controller, note the "\n" to input line breaks:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CreatePO(PONewViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var createPOResult = _managePOsAppServ
            .CreateNewPOHeaderAndDetail(CurrentFacilityId, CurrentUserId, viewModel.VendorId,
                viewModel.CustomerId, viewModel.OrderHeaderId, viewModel.ItemId, viewModel.QtyToOrder,
                viewModel.UnitCost);

        return Json(createPOResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    var modelStateErrors = this.ModelState.Keys.SelectMany(key => this.ModelState[key].Errors);
    string errorMessage = "";
    if (modelStateErrors.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var error in modelStateErrors)
        {
            errorMessage += error.ErrorMessage + "\n";
        }
    }

    return Json(ActionConfirmation<int>.CreateFailureConfirmation(errorMessage, -1,false).Message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

However, the \n is being displayed in the alert box. So it seems the returned Json is escaping the \n. How do I get it to be recognized as a line break?

Javascript:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {        
        alert(xhr.responseText);
        hideLoading();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `CreateFailureConfirmation` do? I don't see anything in here escaping strings, so maybe it's there.

Comment: Have you tried "\\n"?

Comment: @Jacob - no there is nothing escaping it in CreateFailureConfirmation.

Comment: @AlexeyAza - yes I have tried that, and then \\n is displayed in the alert box.

Comment: How are you alerting the data? Sounds like you're maybe alerting the JSON string, not the JavaScript string.

Comment: What is the type of ActionConfirmation<int>.CreateFailureConfirmation(errorMessage, -1,false).Message? Could you show some example data stored in this property?

Comment: @Jacob - yes you were correct. You need to parse the Json string first. Changing `alert(xhr.responseText)` to `alert(jQuery.parseJSON(xhr.responseText));` fixed it. I'd be happy to credit you with the answer if you post the answer. Thank you to both of you for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help, Chad. I've converted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you alerting the data? Sounds like you're maybe alerting the JSON string, not the JavaScript string. Make sure you parse the JSON in your result by changing  `alert(xhr.responseText)` to `alert(jQuery.parseJSON(xhr.responseText));`